# vue js transition not displaying correctly

Tags: vue.js, vue-transitions

i have a problem with transitions with vue js. In chrome it kinda works but it's weird,
and in microsoft edge it's not displaying at all. i don't know how to explain it so i will put a jsfiddle link to my code so you can see what i mean.
link : [my code](https://jsfiddle.net/eL03yswx/)

```
/* animation*/
.slide-fade-enter-active,
.slide-fade-leave-active {
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

.slide-fade-enter,
.slide-fade-leave-to {
    transform: translateX(25%);
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Adding `min-height: 100vh` on .shop-list helps?

Comment: it kinda helps but it's still weird on the enter animation.

Comment: i just realised that in edge there's a lot of errors that i don't have in chrome, why ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i solved my problem by doing "z-index=-1;" on the component but it's still not working on edge...